# API call works with Postman, but does not with Axios

Tags: node.js, api, axios, postman

I am using third party API. The way it works is:

1. I send post request then Token is returned in response.
2. Then i use that Token to check status. Afterwards, report is returned in response 
   In postman, i make both calls separately and it is working, but in Axios I have 1 async function and 2 await Promises.

Postman(NodeJs - Axios) looks like this:

For getting Token:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "security": {
    "pLogin": "a",
    "pPassword": "io"
  },
  "data": {
    "pHead": "005",
    "pCode": "00433",
    "pLegal": 1,
    "pClaimId": "z4LpXRWZKecSnL-FQtgD",
    "pReportId": 8,
    "pReportFormat": 1
  }
});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://10.22.50.10/report/',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

For getting Report with the token:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "data": {
    "pHead": "005",
    "pCode": "00433",
    "pToken": "kgqjismxdrpjnjaqnlnbmovcsvnkarfd",
    "pClaimId": "z4LpXRWZKecSnL-FQtgD",
    "pReportFormat": 1
  }
});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://10.22.50.10/report/status',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

My async function with Axios:

```
/* 1. Searching for client in database (Full name is used, but can be changed)*/
    const client = await client.findOne({
        name: body.name,
        family_name: body.family_name,
        patronymic: body.patronymic
    });

    if (!client) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Client is not registered" });
    }

    /* 2. If client was found in database, make an API call */
    let credit_report;
    try{
        credit_report = await axios.post(
            'http://10.22.50.10/report',
            {
                security: {
                    pLogin: 'a',
                    pPassword: 'io',
                },
                data: {
                    pHead: "005",
                    pCode: "00433",
                    pLegal: 1,
                    pClaimId: client.claim_id,
                    pReportId: 8,
                    pReportFormat: 1
                }
            },
            {
                headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        );
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(400).json({errorMessage: err.message})
    }
    // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

    if(!credit_report.data.data.token) return res.status(400).json({message: credit_report.data});
    const credit_report_status = await axios.post(
        'http://10.22.50.10/report/status',
        {
            data: {
                pHead: "005",
                pCode: "00433",
                pToken: credit_report.data.data.token,
                pClaimId: client.claim_id,
                pReportFormat: 1
            }
        },
        {
            headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    );
    console.log(credit_report_status)
    if(credit_report_status.data.data.result == '05000') return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Client fetched.', clientData64: credit_report_status.data.data.reportBase64});
    else return res.status(400).json({message: credit_report_status.data})
```

When I am using Postman to check my module, it is saying Error 400 Bad Request

Comment: There is an issue with second Promise, as first one returns a Token

Comment: I have tried using second promise in a separate module. it works with exactly same syntax. But combined promises dont work(