# Multiple awaits inside one async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I have an `async` function that contains 3 awaits, like this:

```js
const sequenceOfCalls = async(req, res, next) =>{
   await mongoQuery();
   await apiCall1();
   await apiCall2(); 
}
```

`apiCall1` uses response of `mongoQuery` and `apiCall2` uses response of `apiCall1`.

The problem is `apiCall2` is not working properly (I already have verified all entry params of `apiCall2` and response of `apiCall1`).

What possible issue might there be? Please help as I've been stuck at this for many hours.

If you would like to look at the code, I have posted previously in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915793/api-call-works-with-postman-but-does-not-with-axios)

**EDIT** 
I will try to be as most descriptive and clear as possible. 
Information about the API: 
I have a API called KATM(responds only to authorized IP addresses)
They provide a report and in order to get that report I need to do 3 steps:
 1)register the client with Claim_id 
2)Send a request for the report with the Claim_id that was registered earlier. And this responds with a Token
3)Use the token provided. And this finally provides a report.
Information about the source code: 
How I am registering users:
exports.register = async(req, res, next) => {
const body = req.body;

```
    /* 1. Searching for client in database */
    const client = await Katm_client.findOne({
        name: body.name,
        family_name: body.family_name,
        patronymic: body.patronymic,
    });

    /* 2. If client exists in database */
    if (client) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Client already registered" });
        // throw new Error("Client already exists");//return...ns
    }

    /* 3. If client does not exist in database, create a Client object that will be passed to mongo Model and KATM */
    client_object = {
        claim_id: nanoid(20),
        claim_date: moment().format("DD.MM.YYYY"),
        claim_number: Math.random().toFixed(10).replace("0.", ""),
        agreement_date: moment().format("DD.MM.YYYY"),
        agreement_number: Math.random().toFixed(10).replace("0.",""),
        family_name: body.family_name,
        name: body.name,
        patronymic: body.patronymic,
    };
    const new_client = new Katm_client(client_object)

    /* 4. Make a call to KATM api with Client object */
    const katm_registration = await axios.post(
        'http://10.22.50.3:8000/inquiry/individual',
        {
            header:{ 
                type: "B",
                code: "00433"
            }, 
            request: client_object
            
        },
        {
            headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        
    );

    /* 5. Handling response from the api */
    if(katm_registration.data.result.code == "05000" && katm_registration.data.result.message == "Успешно"){
        const savedClient = await new_client.save();
        return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Client registered and saved in database.', client: new_client});
    }else{
        return res.status(500).json({ message: katm_registration.data });
    }
```

Next I am using one module to get the token, then use it to get the report like this:

```
exports.get_report_credit_info = async(req, res, next) => {
    const body = req.body;

    /* 1. Searching for client in database (Full name is used, but can be changed)*/
    const client = await Katm_client.findOne({
        name: body.name,
        family_name: body.family_name,
        patronymic: body.patronymic
    });

    if (!client) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Client is not registered" });
    }

    /* 2. If client was found in database, make first API call */
    let credit_report;
    try{
        credit_report = await axios.post(
            'http://10.22.50.3:8001/katm-api/v1/credit/report',
            {
                security: {
                    pLogin: 'm',
                    pPassword: 'io',
                },
                data: {
                    pHead: "005",
                    pCode: "00433",
                    pLegal: 1,
                    pClaimId: client.claim_id,
                    pReportId: 8,
                    pReportFormat: 1
                }
            },
            {
                headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        );
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(400).json({errorMessage: err.message})
    }
    if(!credit_report.data.data.token) return res.status(400).json({message: credit_report.data});
    /* 2. Second API call to get Report */
    status_data = {
        pHead: "005",
        pCode: "00433",
        pToken: credit_report.data.data.token,
        pClaimId: client.claim_id,
        pReportFormat: 1
    }
    console.log(status_data)
    let credit_report_status;
    try{
        credit_report_status = await axios.post(
            'http://10.22.50.3:8001/katm-api/v1/credit/report/status', { data: status_data },
            {
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
            }
        );
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(400).json({errorMessage: err.message})
    };
    if(credit_report_status.data.data.result == '05000') return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Client fetched.', clientData64: credit_report_status.data.data.reportBase64});
    else return res.status(400).json({message: credit_report_status.data})
};
```

**What I have tried:**
I separated second await(`credit_report_status`) API call for getting the report and it worked, but as soon as I add second await(`credit_report_status`) API calls, then it does not work again.

 I am getting a token, which means first await `credit_report` is working correctly. I assume second await(`credit_report_status`) is not going through or something
As you can see I store entry parameters of (`credit_report_status`) as object then pass it to the Axios. I logged it out to make sure and it has correct info.

The problem is second(last) await(Promise) is working 1 out of 15 times. API does not have any issues, since I am constantly checking it with Postman

Comment: Currently you're not post does not give a complete and reproducible example of your problem. Make sure your question is self-contained and holds all the information necessary for others to help you.

Comment: @Webber, Im not sure how to do that since the APIs used is not accessible to public.

Comment: You are saying that parameters of apiCall2 are OK, so the function actually receives the correct data after apiCall1. If my understanding is correct, then there is nothing to do with the call sequence and the problem is inside apiCall2. 
Also, your sample code is not correct: as there is no parameter passing.

Comment: @slkorolev, there is parameters passing. 1) mongoQuery() retrieving client and  client.claimId is being passed to apiCall1()"PClaimId parameter". 2) client.claimId and token(retrieved from response of apiCall1()) are being passed to apiCall2() "pToken: credit_report.data.data.token,". Also, I tried using await apiCall2() in separate module and it is working perfectly

Comment: Can you update your question so it is concrete about the api, the api calls and the parameters? As it stands there is not enough info about the problem. All info should be inside the question, not behind a link.

Comment: @Rasul Can you code a sample of all functions.

Comment: The code as posted is 100% correct and 100% bug free. There is nothing wrong with the code and I can guarantee that the posted code works correctly. What is not working is obviously in code you are not showing us.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle proving that the code you posted works with no bugs: https://jsfiddle.net/r7ehyvgk/

Comment: @RahulSharma , I edited the question check it out.

Comment: @slebetman,  I edited the question check it out.

Comment: @trincot,  I edited the question check it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Context**

As you say the implementation from the calls is not available to you, you have two options.

**First**

You can create a try catch block around your calls and output any errors the calls may be throwing.

```js
const sequenceOfCalls = async(req, res, next) =>{
  try {
    await mongoQuery();
    await apiCall1();
    await apiCall2(); 
  } catch (error) {
    // do something with the error, so that you can see it
    console.log(error)
    res.status(400).send('An unexpected error occurred')
  }

  next();
}
```

**Second**

If the error is not descriptive enough and you need to know what happens on the other end, then your only option is to contact the maintainer of the API that you are calling.

Comment: There is no error. and the API is working correctly because i have tested both calls on Postman and they do work. I noticed just now apiCall2 works when isolated in a module, but as soon as I combine apiCall1 and apiCall2 then apiCall2 stops working

Comment: You're saying "not working" but this is ambiguous if it also doesn't give a response and it also doesn't give you an error. You say Postman works and gives you output. Try to compare that to the output you're getting from the calls that you're debugging.